# JS: Text to Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, text-processing, bmp

I'm currently making a toy project that converts a string of text into a series of GitHub commits. The end result should look something like this:

[image: GitHub Green dots example]

The solution I am currently working on is to take a string of text and convert each character to a 7x7 array of boolean values, where `true` is a green dot, and `false` is not. Then I'll iterate over that to come up with an array of commits to send to GitHub.

For the first part, I've been searching for an npm package that takes text, like ascii characters and returns a bmp or similar image representing the text, but I haven't had any luck.

Does anybody know of a library that will do something like that? My main requirement is that I can set the 'resolution' of the output, so I can get a 7x7 image from it. Alternatively, if there is an entirely different solution, I'd be happy to hear that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using node.js, you could use [opencv4node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs). It has features to write text to an image, that are normally used to annotate images, but should work well for your case.

The image could be whatever grid size you prefer. Then you could iterate over the pixels and use their coordinates to determine the commits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just got it working and have rendered a `cv.Mat` object to a bmp file with some text I've entered. I should definitely be able to use this to generate commit data.